# hidden Bad scheduled job

Tags: scheduler, rundeck

I have a Rundeck Rundeck 3.1.2-20190927 community, a Project with a scheduled job at 01:02:00 CET , and it works. BUT every night, I get a notification for this same job, scheduled at 00:00:00 CET ! I can't find any info in database or WebUI, can anybody help me ?

Thank you !

Nicolas

Comment: Hi! Can you share your job definition and the way how do you launch rundeck? (maybe you're set timezone on startup like this: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/2072#issuecomment-252400455).

Comment: Hi!

Please find xml job :

https://gist.github.com/hackman61/9791157e5179d8b8a1202096f47a91e1

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same timezone configured in your Rundeck server, you don't need to specify it, remove the timezone of your job definition and your job runs using the Rundeck server timezone.